# Adding a 1 to many file upload to CRUD

Tags: atk4

My app has sales listing functionality that will allow the user to add 1 or more photos for the product that they want to sell.

I'm attempting to use the upload/filestore_image of ATK with a Join table to create the relationship - my models:

```
class Model_Listing extends Model_Table {

public $entity_code='listing';

function init(){
    parent::init();
    $this->addField('name');
    $this->addField('body')->type('text');
    $this->addField('status');

    $this->addField('showStatus')->calculated(true);
}

function calculate_showStatus(){

    return ($this->status == 1) ? "Sold" : "For Sale" ;
}
}

class Model_listingimages extends Model_Table {

public $entity_code='listing_images';

function init(){
    parent::init();
    $this->addField('listing_id')->refModel('Model_Listing');
    $this->addField('filestore_image_id')->refModel('Model_Filestore_Image');
}
}
```

In my page manager class I have added the file upload to the crud:

```
class page_manager extends Page {
function init(){
    parent::init();

    $tabs=$this->add('Tabs');
$s = $tabs->addTab('Sales')->add('CRUD');
$s->setModel('Listing',array('name','body','status'),array('name','status'));

if ($s->form) {
   $f = $s->form;
   $f->addField('upload','Add Photos')->setModel('Filestore_Image');
   $f->add('FileGrid')->setModel('Filestore_Image');
}
}
```

}

My questions:

1. I am getting a "Unable to include FileGrid.php" error - I want the user to be able to see the images that they have uploaded and hoped that this would be the best way to do so - by adding the file grid to bottom of the form. - EDIT - ignore this question, I created a FileGrid class based on the code in the example link below - that fixed the issue.
2. How do I make the association between the CRUD form so that a submit will save the uploaded files and create entries in the join table?

I have installed the latest release of ATK4, added the 4 filestore tables to the db and referenced the following page in the documentation http://codepad.agiletoolkit.org/image

TIA
PG

Comment: btw, do you know that single field allows you to upload multiple pictures? https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Form/Field/upload.php You will also need to define "image" field as varchar, but unless you are putting indexes on that field it should be OK. I'll think about your other questions and will reply later.

Comment: yes - the user can add as many images as they want (though I may add a limit at a later date).  The filestore_image sql created 4 tables - filestore_image.name is defined as varchar. I want to be able to build a relationship between the listing table and the filestore_image table using my listing_images join table/model - unless you think that there is abetter way to achieve this.

Comment: I don't have to use the filestore_image with a join table - I'm happy to just to have an image upload to a dedicated table - as the listing will have a 1 to many to the images but seeing as most of the heavy lifting has already been coded in the filestore_image it seemed as though it would be easier to try and implement and use that.

Answer (score 0):

## By creating model based on Filestore_File

You need to specify a proper model. By proper I mean:

- It must be extending Model_Filestore_File
- It must have MasterField set to link it with your entry

In this case, however you must know the referenced ID when the images are being uploaded, so it won't work if you upload image before creating record. Just to give you idea the code would look

```
$mymodel=$this->add('Model_listingimages');
$mymodel->setMasterField('listing_id',$listing_id);
$upload_field->setModel($mymodel);
$upload_field->allowMultiple();
```

This way all the images uploaded through the field will automatically be associated with your listing. You will need to inherit model from Model_Filestore_File. The Model_Filestore_Image is a really great example which you can use. You should add related entity (join) and define fields in that table.

There is other way too:

## By doing some extra work in linking images

When form is submitted, you can retrieve list of file IDs by simply getting them.

```
$form->get('add_photos')
```

Inside form submission handler you can perform some manual insertion into listingimages.

```
$form->onSubmit(function($form) uses($listing_id){
    $photos = explode(',',$form->get('add_photos'));
    $m=$form->add('Model_listingimages');
    foreach($photos as $photo_id){
        $m->unloadDdata()->set('listing_id',$listing_id)
            ->set('filestore_image_id',$photo_id)->update();
    }
}); // I'm not sure if this will be called by CRUD, which has
    // it's own form submit handler, but give it a try.
```

You must be careful, through, if you use global model inside the upload field without restrictions, then user can access or delete images uploaded by other users. If you use file model with MVCGrid you should see what files they can theoretically get access to. That's normal and that's why I recommend using the first method described above.

NOTE: you should not use spaces in file name, 2nd argument to addField, it breaks javascript.